# Plotting arbitrary data for repository

Tags: version-control, jenkins, dvcs

I'm looking for a way to visualize arbitrary information about my repository over time, which might be some version-dependent number, such as:

- lines of code
- number of lines in a latex document
- time between commits
- anything that can be output by a script

What is the best way to visualize this information?

More specifically, I'm using mercurial and would ideally like something with a decent interface, with plot resizing/scrolling/etc...  Jenkins' plot plugin is decent but not great, but more importantly it's not possible to visualize **past** data (say, after adding a new metric).

Comment: This sounds more like a job for an analysis application like Sonar (http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Historical+Information) which also has a Jenkins plugin. Are you looking for something like this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would suggest to split your task to simplify everything a little bit. It is likely you will need several different tools in order to collect and visualize all required information. Historical view seems to be another big challenge.

**Lines of code**

There are several plugins available for Jenkins, but almost all are highly specialized. [SLOCCount plug-in](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/SLOCCount+Plugin) seems to be most universal, but it does not provide any graphical output.

[image]

- [NSIQ Collector Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/NSIQ+Collector+Plugin)
- [SLOCCount plug-in](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/SLOCCount+Plugin)
- [JavaNCSS Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/JavaNCSS+Plugin)

There might be some other option for your language. For example, [CCCC](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/CCCC+Plugin) will provide required information for C and C++ code:

[image]

**Number of lines in a latex document**
I see several options to achieve that:

- adapt existing solution/plugin
- use repository statistics tool ([Pepper](http://scm-pepper.sourceforge.net/), for example, can do the trick)
- use simple shell script to count lines and report it

[Pepper](http://scm-pepper.sourceforge.net/) will generate something like the following:

[image]

Please check Pepper [gallery](http://scm-pepper.sourceforge.net/gallery/). There are another tools, for example: [hgchart](https://bitbucket.org/mg/hgchart/wiki/Home)

**Time between commits**

The simplest solution is to let a commit to trigger some trivial job, so Jenkins will provide all information as part of build history (with a timeline, etc).

[image]

Another solution is to use repository statistics tool once again:

[image]

**Anything that can be output by a script**

There are several good plug-ins for that.

- [Plot plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Plot+Plugin) can visualize multiple values provided as properties or csv file.
- [Measurement Plots Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Measurement+Plots+Plugin) scans the output in order to find values to be visualized

[image]

Happy continuous integration.

Comment: +1 For using images in your answer. Also very nicely outlined. I'd +1 again.