# Any suggestions about how jmeter can be used to do regression testing for page load times

Tags: jenkins, jmeter, regression-testing

I am thinking to put automated regression tests in place for page load times. We have few deployment scenarios and I think we could use jmeter with Jenkins/hudson integration, but I am not sure how to go about it and what are the best practices to implement it.

Can you suggest what could be the approach to implement such regression test?

Are there any better alternative if not jmeter?

Comment: There was some good discussion on jmeter list, though no conclusion. http://jmeter.512774.n5.nabble.com/Any-suggestions-about-how-jmeter-can-be-used-to-do-regression-testing-for-page-load-times-td5718026.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that either with JMeter or with Grinder.

[Performance Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Performance+Plugin) will do the trick for you:

[image]

Please check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14246284/1435741)

You can also use [Plot Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Plot+Plugin) to visualize any data you want, for example you can define your own key performance metrics (KPIs).

[image]

You can find more details [Plotting arbitrary data for repository.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14238185/1435741)

Comment: Thanks for really illustrated answer.

Comment: I really want to use the Jenkins 'Performance Plugin', but after 20 performance builds, clicking the reports causes the server to hang at 100% CPU for more than 5 minutes, any suggestions?

Comment: I would suggest to use VisualVM in order to pin down problem in several seconds. Anyway, this is strange behaviour I've never seen.